# Removing diagonal elements from a sparse matrix in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to remove diagonal elements from a sparse matrix. Since the matrix is sparse, these elements shouldn't be stored once removed.

Scipy provides a method to set diagonal elements values: [setdiag](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.spmatrix.setdiag.html#scipy.sparse.spmatrix.setdiag)

If I try it using lil_matrix, it works:

```
>>> a = np.ones((2,2))
>>> c = lil_matrix(a)
>>> c.setdiag(0)
>>> c
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

However with csr_matrix, it seems diagonal elements are not removed from storage:

```
>>> b = csr_matrix(a)
>>> b
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> b.setdiag(0)
>>> b
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> b.toarray()
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.]])
```

Through a dense array, we have of course:

```
>>> csr_matrix(b.toarray())
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Is that intended? If so, is it due to the compressed format of csr matrices? Is there any workaround else than going from sparse to dense to sparse again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply setting elements to 0 does not change the sparsity of a `csr` matrix.  You have to apply `eliminate_zeros`.

```
In [807]: a=sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((2,2)))
In [808]: a
Out[808]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [809]: a.setdiag(0)
In [810]: a
Out[810]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [811]: a.eliminate_zeros()
In [812]: a
Out[812]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Since changing the sparsity of a csr matrix is relatively expensive, they let you change values to 0 without changing sparsity.

```
In [829]: %%timeit a=sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((1000,1000)))
     ...: a.setdiag(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.86 ms per loop

In [830]: %%timeit a=sparse.csr_matrix(np.ones((1000,1000)))
     ...: a.setdiag(0)
     ...: a.eliminate_zeros()
SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
10 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop

In [831]: %%timeit a=sparse.lil_matrix(np.ones((1000,1000)))
     ...: a.setdiag(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: Precisely what I missed. Thanks!